# Pyramid: how come view callables accept either one or two parameters?

Tags: python, pyramid

A Pyramid view callable in it's most simple form can be written as:

```
def myview(request):
    pass
```

An alternative form is to accept another parameter -- the context:

```
def myview(context, request):
    pass
```

How does the Pyramid view lookup machinery know whether view callable accepts a context or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pyramid inspects the view using the `inspect` module (specifically the `.getargspec()` call in the [`requestonly()` function](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/config/views.py#L505):

```
def requestonly(view, attr=None):
    ismethod = False
    if attr is None:
        attr = '__call__'
    if inspect.isroutine(view):
        fn = view
    elif inspect.isclass(view):
        try:
            fn = view.__init__
        except AttributeError:
            return False
        ismethod = hasattr(fn, '__call__')
    else:
        try:
            fn = getattr(view, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            return False

    try:
        argspec = inspect.getargspec(fn)
    except TypeError:
        return False

    args = argspec[0]

    if hasattr(fn, im_func) or ismethod:
        # it's an instance method (or unbound method on py2)
        if not args:
            return False
        args = args[1:]
    if not args:
        return False

    if len(args) == 1:
        return True

    defaults = argspec[3]
    if defaults is None:
        defaults = ()

    if args[0] == 'request':
        if len(args) - len(defaults) == 1:
            return True

    return False
```

The rest of the code then adjusts the code path to omit the context if the view doesn't accept a context.

Comment: Could you link to where this happens on Pyramid github source? ( https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/master/pyramid )

Comment: Probably here: https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/config/views.py

Comment: Thanks.  So adding a route will run the inspection ( as @Martijn pointed out ), which will then 'wrap' the view into a standardized call, and store that in the registry via `DefaultViewMapper`.  `router.py` (https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/router.py) has the `Router.handle_request` method which invokes the mapped(standardized) request with both params `response = view_callable(context, request)`.  

I was actually always interested in exactly how this was done too.  It's nice that they optimized the check via the `DefaultViewMapper` standardizations.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco: Yes, my apologies; had to step away for a while.